# After installing Wacom Bamboo Capture tablet, Windows treats right Alt key as AltGr

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout, graphics-tablet, modifier-keys

After I installed a Wacom Bamboo Capture tablet on my Windows 7 laptop and enabled the Tablet PC Tools, Windows displays a tooltip whenever I press a modifier key while I use the tablet (which is probably normal), but the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is being shown as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key)):

[image: AltGr shown when right Alt key is pressed]

The keyboard layout is English (United States), not International. Can this be changed?  Should I be concerned?

Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 64-bit running on HP Pavilion dv6z-3000 Select Edition laptop.  All tablet drivers up to date.

Comment: The right hand key is labelled `AltGr` on my keyboard. Perhaps it's just reset to it's proper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you've read the Wikipedia article you linked. Did you check to make sure that your keyboard is set to US English and not International in Regional and Language Settings (in the Control Panel)? The tablet software may have changed the keyboard layout, though I surmise it might've done that in order to provide certain features of the tablet.

Try pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> -- that is, <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> if it were a normal US English layout. Do you get a copyright symbol? If so, you're probably using the "US International" keyboard layout rather than the plain US English.

Comment: As noted in the question, I am not using the International keyboard layout.  The key still behaves as a normal Alt key, regardless of whether the pen is in proximity of the tablet or whether I'm drawing on it.  I'm not getting the copyright symbol when I press `R Alt`+`C`.

Comment: Then the tooltips that pop up are somehow hard-coded to display certain pre-determined values that the Wacom drivers determined. If it's not dependent on your keyboard layout, then they could've caused it to pop up a tooltip saying "I'm a monkey!" when you press Right Alt. It's easy to implement something random that doesn't integrate properly with the operating system. Wacom seems to have done that. Although... if you were prompted to select your language when you installed the drivers, **that** could be related.

Comment: Should I be concerned about this condition?  In the English/US keyboard layout, will this cause any problems?